# How to add new Guid to a String List?

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, authentication, guid

I get "object referance not set to an instance...." error. I comment the line...

```
        public Guid Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            Guid result = new Guid();
```

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            userName = userName.Trim();
            password = password.Trim();

            Member member = BusinessDb.LoginDbJobs.GetUser(userName);

            if (member != null && member.PasswordDb == password)
            {
                result = Guid.NewGuid();
                Members.Live.Add(result); //--->Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And Member class is;

```
...
    public class Members
    {
        public static List< Guid > Live;
    }
...
```

So how can I add the "new Guid", to "List< string > Live" ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
public class Members
{
    public static List<Guid> Live = new List<Guid>();
}
```

You declare `Live` but not initialize it, so `Live` is null!!

Comment: Damn, nice catch... Thank you very much to both of you... How I did such a mistake...

Answer (score 2):

There's no indication that you ever assign a value to your variable. For example, you might want to change `Members` to:

```
public class Members
{
    public static readonly List<Guid> Live = new List<Guid>();
}
```

If you don't do that - and don't assign it a value anywhere else - it will always have a value of `null`, which is why you're getting that exception.

Note that I would strongly urge you *not* to use global state like this in the first place, and also *not* to have public fields.